# How to sequentially click on child elements in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a `table` with a variable number of `tr` elements. Each `tr` is clickable and when clicked a modal opens (always the same modal for each `tr`). In the modal a toggle has to be set:

```js
it('Set payment methods', () => {
    cy.el('tablePaymentMethods')
        .children()
        .each(($el, index) => {
            cy.intercept({
                method: 'PATCH',
                url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/api/v1/company/*/paymentMethod/*?cache_buster=*`,
            }).as('paymentMethod');
            cy.wrap($el).click();
            cy.el('toggleActive').click();
            cy.el('btnEditPaymentMethod').click();
            cy.wait('@paymentMethod').then((data: any) => {
                expect(data.response.body.data.active).to.eq(true);
            });
        });
});
```

The problem with this test is that Cypress executes them at the same time, showing me the error:

> is being covered by another element

I can use `force: true` to still click on the toggle but I would much rather wait with clicking on the second `tr` when the `cy.wait()` has gotten a response (meaning the first modal is closed).

Comment: How are you closing your modal before clicking on the next `tr`?

Comment: `cy.el('btnEditPaymentMethod').click();` this button saves the state and closes the modal. The issue that I'm not clicking on the next tr. The `.each` executes the code for both `tr` elements simultaneously.

Comment: Good to know. My next guess is whether  `.children()` returns the correcet `tr`s.

Comment: Looks like a **faulty intercept** - if you run a reproducible example it works perfectly.